# sudo apt-get -f install error недостаточно места на диске?

Tags: linux, apt-get

При выполнении команды для починки зависимости пакетов.

```
 sudo apt-get -а install
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Распаковывается linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic (4.4.0-134.160) …
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic_4.4.0-134.160_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 не удалось скопировать извлечённые данные «./boot/System.map-4.4.0-134-generic» в «/boot/System.map-4.4.0-134-generic.dpkg-new»: **ошибка записи (На устройстве не осталось свободного места)**
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как получено сообщение об ошибке о нехватке места на диске
                                                                                         dpkg-deb: ошибка: подпроцесс вставка уничтожен по сигналу (Обрыв канала)
```

Пишет **ошибка записи (На устройстве не осталось свободного места)**

Хотя при выводе df -h место на диске достаточно в корневом катологе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: inode не закончились?

Comment: Вон там человечьим языком написано, что на /boot занято 100%

Comment: Да, прочитал инструкцию как почистить раздел /boot если он заполнен на 100%. И помогло. А зачем разделу /boot выделяют так мало памяти?

Comment: @manking да это не мало. Другой вопрос сколько вы туда ядер напихали и зачем.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev
Ну этот сервер уже был. Никто не знает как там все создавали, сейчас разбираюсь. А в чем смысл такого разделения? Не проще ли сейчас монтировать только корневой каталог?

Comment: @manking смысл в отделении от корневого каталога всего-что-вообще-только-можно есть всегда. Во-первых, так гораздо труднее переполнить корень, а заодно и всю файловую систему, коль скоро она не разделена. Во-вторых, чем больше и занятее (в смысле количества записей на неё в единицу времени) файловая система, тем с большей вероятностью она упадёт. А упавший корень — это _очень_ неприятно.

Comment: при установке корня на lvm отдельный /boot — это необходимость т.к. загрузчик не может подцепить ядро с lvm'а...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убунту накидала слишком много обновлений ядра в каталог бут.

Зайди в `/boot` и удали `linux` и `initramfs` всех версий кроме той что запущенна сейчас (`uname -a`)

Посмотри список установленных ядер `dpkg -l "linux-image-*"` и удали все кроме текущего и **meta** пакета: `apt-get remove linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64`

И повтори установку через `apt-get -f install`.

Обычно достаточно 75 мегабайт в буте, но если начнешь руками устанавливать ядра - старые не удалятся